# Workaround for when windows scheduled tasks fails when user changes their password

Tags: windows, password, scheduled-task

When a users password changes that users scheduled tasks will fail unless you change the password associated with that task. This is a problem for me as I have a small script that gets run by a scheduled task every day on someone else's server.

They have a policy in place where the users passwords need to be changed every month. This is causing a problem with the scheduled task as it then fails to run. Are there any good solutions to this issue that aren't going to require manual intervention every month or so?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to synchronise scheduled task passwords. The common practice for this sort of thing is to create a service account for running the task and set the password not to expire. You can use a long and complex password for this as you're only likely to use it once then forget about it.